# How use an ASP.NET Core middleware as iismodule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have written a middleware in an ASP.NET Core class library:

```
public class ContentChangeMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I want to use it as iismodule to use this module in an ASP.NET webforms project. What can I do? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to use ASP.NET Core middleware inside the IIS module to achieve your requirement like you wants. If you want to use module in asp.net, you should directly use IHttpModule.

Comment: Ok. I created an HttpModule in this ASP.NET Core project but how can I use this module?

Comment: Any update? Did you have any other question regard this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttpmodule?view=netframework-4.8.1), you could find the ihttpmodule is only work for asp.net not asp.net core. So if you want to use ihttpmodule , you should directly create the module inside your webform to use the httpmodule.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Create a asp.net class library named CustomTestHttpModule:

2.Create the CustomTestHttpModule class as below:

```
public class CustomTestHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
      
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
        context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(OnEndRequest);

    }


    public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Write your custom code here

        // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access 
        // request and response properties. 
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
            context.Response.Write("<h1><font color=red>" + "HelloWorldModule: Beginning of Request" + "</font></h1><hr>");
    }
    public void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Write your custom code here

        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
            context.Response.Write("<hr><h1><font color=red>" + "HelloWorldModule: End of Request</font></h1>");
    }

}
```

3.Add reference inside your web form application:

[image]

4.Add below settings inside your web.config root path:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="CustomHttpModule" type="CustomTestHttpModule.CustomTestHttpModule,CustomTestHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Test result as below:

[image]